# Laravel Command Queue exception

Tags: php, exception, laravel

I'm trying to implement a Laravel 5 queue which sends an new event mail to a mailing list. I found out you can use a Command for this but every time I try to execute this command I get an error exception (see below). The class I've written to do the mailing is the following

```
<?php namespace App\Commands;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use \App\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;

class EventMailing extends Command implements SelfHandling, ShouldBeQueued {

    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $event;
    public $recipients;

    public function __construct(Event $event, $recipients)
    {
        $this->event=$event;
        $this->recipients=$recipients;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(EventMailing $command, User $user)
    {
        $event = $command->event;

        print_r($event);

       /* foreach ($this->recipients as $recipient) {
            Mail::send('emails.event', $event,
                function($message) use ($event,$recipient)
                {
                    $message->from('info@gsebelux.org', 'GSE BeLux');
                    $message->subject('New event: '.$event->name);
                    $message->to($recipient);
                }
            );
        }*/
    }

}
```

Note: I commented out the mailing part to check if it wasn't that part which was malfunctioning.

From a controller I call the EventMailing Command like this:

```
public function sendMail($event,$array)
{
    Queue::push(new EventMailing($event,$array));
}
```

When I trigger this function and I do a php artisan queue:work --verbose
I get this. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
  [ErrorException]                                                                        
  unserialize(): Function spl_autoload_call() hasn't defined the class it was called for  



Exception trace:
 () at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php:36
 Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError() at n/a:n/a
 unserialize() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php:36
 Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php:126
 Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->resolveAndFire() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/BeanstalkdJob.php:51
 Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\BeanstalkdJob->fire() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:207
 Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:159
 Illuminate\Queue\Worker->pop() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php:107
 Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php:67
 Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->fire() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:523
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:115
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:253
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:101
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:90
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at /home/vagrant/Code/artisan:36
```

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I'm dealing with the same error - even for the simplest of commands

Comment: Not realy solved it this way. Did it the old way and created a Queue "EventMailing" and pushed my jobs on it from a controller. In the queue class I created a "fire" method which handled the mailing job. If more people are struggling with this I'll make a blogpost on my website, just ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
public function handle(EventMailing $command, User $user)
{
    $event = $command->event;

    print_r($event);
```

by

```
public function handle(User $user)
{
    //event is in the constructor
    $event = $this->event;

    print_r($event);
```